# React Hook "useState" cannot be called in a class component. React Hooks must be called in a React function component or a custom React Hook function

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui

I'm new in React Frontend developing. I'm trying to add a temporary drawer to my Material-UI NavBar. I've add a drawer in my code:

```
class Navbar extends Component {
    render() {
        const { authenticated } = this.props;
        const [open, setOpen] = useState(false);
        const handleDrawer = () =>{
           setOpen(true)
        }
        return (
            <AppBar position="fixed">
                <Toolbar className="nav-container">
                    {authenticated ? (
                        <Fragment>
                            <IconButton edge="start" onClick={handleDrawer} >
                                <Menu/>
                            </IconButton>
                            <Drawer
                                anchor='left'
                                open={open}
                                onClose={()=> setOpen(false)}
                                >
                                    <h3> Drawer</h3>
                            </Drawer>
                            <NewPost/>
                            <Link to="/">
                                <MyButton tip="Home">
                                    <HomeIcon color = "disabled"/>
                                </MyButton>
                            </Link>
                            <Link to="/chats">
                                <MyButton tip="Chats">
                                    <ChatIcon color = "disabled"/>
                                </MyButton>
                            </Link>
                            <Notifications />
                        </Fragment>
                        

                    ):(
                        <Fragment>
                            <Button color="inherit" component={Link} to="/login">Login</Button>
                            <Button color="inherit" component={Link} to="/signup">Singup</Button>
                            <Button color="inherit" component={Link} to="/">Home</Button>
                            {/* <Button color="inherit" component={Link} to="/user">Profile</Button>*/}
                        </Fragment>
                    )}
                </Toolbar>
            </AppBar>

            
        )
    }
}

Navbar.propTypes = {
    authenticated:  PropTypes.bool.isRequired
}

const mapStateToProps = state =>({
    authenticated: state.user.authenticated
})

export default connect(mapStateToProps)(Navbar)
```

But this error appeared:

```
React Hook "useState" cannot be called in a class component. React Hooks must be called in a React function component or a custom React Hook function
```

So, I've create a constructor to handle this (before render):

```
constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      open: false
    };
  }
```

And when I want to change the state, I've use:

```
this.setState({ open: true })
```

But, when I triggered the Drawer (clicking the button),It does not open. What can I do?

Comment: Try  `open={this.state.open}` instead of `open={open}`.

Comment: Or `const { open } = this.state;` at the top of the render method so `open={open}` works.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The state hook (useState) is available with functional React Components, but in your case you are using a Class component. Functional React components normally don't have states out of the box, but `useState` is a new feature that will let you work around that

You can either change this to functional component, or keep it as a class component and use the state differently
E.g :

- `!this.state.open` instead of `!open`
  and
- `this.setState({open: false})` instead of `setOpen(false)`

https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-state.html

Answer (score 3):

Change this line `const [open, setOpen] = useState(false);` to `this.state = { open: false };`

and when setting to true just call  `this.setState({ open: this.state.open: true })`

Answer (score 1):

You have to use a functional component. Currently your component is a class component, so instead you should have something like:

```
const Navbar = (props) => {
  const { authenticated } = props;
  const [open, setOpen] = useState(false);
  const handleDrawer = () =>{
    setOpen(true)
  }
    
  return (
    <AppBar position="fixed">...</AppBar>
  );
};
```

I also noticed that your class component has the state parts defined in the render method. When using class components, state should be defined in the `constructor` instead, otherwise your state will be overwritten every render.

Answer (score 0):

What about functional component instead of class component?
Functional component is recommended as you know.
I think it's easy to code and it improves performance.

```
const Navbar = () => {
     //useState, define functions here
     return (//the same as render method of your class component) 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

use `function Navbar(props)` in place of `class Navbar extends Component`

Its because, There is a rule that : React Hook "useState" cannot be called in a `class component` e.g. `class Navbar extends Component` . React Hooks must be called in a `React function component` e.g. `function Navbar(props)` or a custom React Hook function